# Composite key in Cassandra with Pig

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

We have a CQL table that looks something like this:

```
CREATE table data (
  occurday  text,
  seqnumber int,
  occurtimems bigint,
  unique bigint,

  fields map<text, text>,

  primary key ((occurday, seqnumber), occurtimems, unique)
)
```

I can query this table from `cqlsh` like this:

```
select * from data where seqnumber = 10 AND occurday = '2013-10-01';
```

This query works and returns the expected data.

If I execute this query as part of a `LOAD` from within Pig, however, things don't work.

```
-- Need to URL encode the query
data = LOAD 'cql://ks/data?where_clause=seqnumber%3D10%20AND%20occurday%3D%272013-10-01%27' USING CqlStorage();
```

gives

```
InvalidRequestException(why:seqnumber cannot be restricted by more than one relation if it includes an Equal)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$prepare_cql3_query_result.read(Cassandra.java:39567)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_prepare_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1625)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.prepare_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1611)
at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingRecordReader$RowIterator.prepareQuery(CqlPagingRecordReader.java:591)
at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingRecordReader$RowIterator.executeQuery(CqlPagingRecordReader.java:621)
```

Shouldn't these behave the same? Why is the version through Pig failing where the straight `cqlsh` command works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadoop is using [CqlPagingRecordReader](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/hadoop/cql3/CqlPagingRecordReader.java) to try to load your data. This is leading to queries that are not identical to what you have entered. The paging record reader is trying to obtain small slices of Cassandra data at a time to avoid timeouts.

This means that your query is executed as

```
SELECT * FROM "data" WHERE token("occurday","seqnumber") > ? AND
token("occurday","seqnumber") <= ? AND occurday='A Great Day' 
AND seqnumber=1 LIMIT 1000 ALLOW FILTERING
```

And this is why you are seeing your repeated key error. I'll submit a bug to the Cassandra Project.

Jira:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6151

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you add the JIRA number to your answer once you know it?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. But looks like there is no resolution (on jira) to this problem. @Chad, did you overcome this by any means? any workarounds?

Comment: I hadn't looked at the JIRA for a while, so I was quite surprised to find that they've closed it as "Won't Fix". Their suggestion is to perform all of the filtering within Pig, but there's obviously the issue of inefficiencies if you have many partitions. (This is what we ended up doing.) In theory, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6311 should make things better, but it looks like it's targeted only to Cassandra 2.x.

Comment: Any chance you can post how you were able to know what the raw cassandra query that pig created was? Seems like pig -d DEBUG -v is not helping to figure out what query Cassandra is getting from pig.